# Parse syslog and only match entries within the last x minutes

Tags: python

I need to create a script that will run every 5 minutes via cron and parse syslog, but only match the entries within the last 5 minutes of the execution time.

If there a module I can leverage for part of this?  If so, will it work when running at midnight when the date is one day ahead?  The date format of my log is:

```
Jun 20 14:04:47 <log msg details>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html)'s `strptime` function:

```
>>> datetime.strptime("Jun 20 14:04:47", "%b %d %H:%M:%S")
# => datetime.datetime(1900, 6, 20, 14, 4, 47)
```

You can then use simple operators like `<` to compare datetimes. (You'll have to be aware that if a year is not specified, it will default to 1900.)

Answer (score 2):

I had to write a script that parses the syslog continuously (think "tail -f"), so the case is slightly different, but maybe this helps anyway. I parsed each line using this regex. depending your your syslog implementation you'll have to adapt of course.

```
pattern=re.compile("^(?P<month>[a-zA-Z]{3})\s+(?P<day>\d\d?)\s(?P<hour>\d\d)\:(?P<minute>\d\d):(?P<second>\d\d)(?:\s(?P<suppliedhost>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\s(?P<host>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\s(?P<process>[a-zA-Z0-9\/_-]+)(\[(?P<pid>\d+)\])?:\s(?P<message>.+)$")
```

then I could convert it into a datetime object

```
minute=int(m.group('minute'))
hour=int(m.group('hour'))
day=int(m.group('day'))
second=int(m.group('second'))
month=monthindex[m.group('month')]
now=datetime.datetime.utcnow()
year=now.year
ts=datetime.datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)
```

you could then check for each line if that object is within the last 5 minutes.

your problem will be that you'll have to parse the whole syslog in each run unless you store the last file position somewhere.

Comment: This is basically what I am trying to do.  I could not think of an easy way to store the position of the file between runs, especially when the log rotates.  The easiest approach I could think of is the one I described.  Unfortunately "tail -f" is not an option for me.

Comment: storing the position is not that complicated. on your file object you have `file.tell()` which returns the current byte no. store this value in a file in /tmp,  in the next run, check, if the file has been rolled over (filesize smaller than last position), in that case read from the beginning. if its still the same log, forward to the last position : ``file.seek(position)`` and continue reading from there